# PROBLEMA PARA MOSTRAR IMAGENES EN MI FRONTEND INSTANTANEAMENTE AL GUARDARLAS PREVIAMENTE EN MI BACKEND

Tags: reactjs, redux

Sere breve, confiando en la gran familia stackoverflow, necesito un ejemplo en react, donde se guarde una imagen en una base de datos(mongoDB por ejemplo) y luego se muestre inmediatamente esa imagen en mi frontend, es decir, el cliente selecciona dos imagenes por ejemplo, le da click a un boton y luego se muestra inmediatamente al instante las 2 imagenes en mi frontend pero sin recargar la pagina, esto ultimo es muy importante para mi: "que no recargue la pagina al mostrar las imagenes", seria fabuloso si tambien se usara REDUX. No veo mucho sentido colocar aca mi proyecto de imagenes porque seria muy extenso, por ello pienso que un simple ejemplo colocado aqui de la comunidad seria suficiente para mi, en mi proyecto de imagenes en React es precisamente ese el problema que tengo: "selecciono dos imagenes(por ejemplo), le doy click a un boton de envio, se guarda todo perfecto en mi base de datos de mongo, pero al hacer el dispach dentro de mi funcion de guardar imagenes se me recarga la pagina y no se me muestran las imagenes en mi frontend que se guardaron previamente mi store, tambien probe colocando mi dispatch en el UseEffect y lo mismo, se recarga la pagina y no me muestra las imagenes guardadas", todo esto han sido dias golpeandome la cabeza y no puedo lograr que una vez enviadas las imagenes se me muestren inmediatamanete en mi frontend sin que se recargue la pagina. He colocado 2 preguntas en stackoverflow sobre otros asuntos sin obtener respuesta de la comunidad quizas eran preguntas muy dificiles jeje pero sigo confiando en la gran familia de stackoverflow que en esta pregunta si me responderan y ayudaran. Espero haya algun sabio por alli jeje. Mil gracias de antemano.

He logrado resolver el problema de recarga de la pagina al guardar imagenes, ya puedo guardar imagenes y mostrarlas instantaneamente, PERO AHORA SE ME HA PRESENTADO UN PROBLEMA: "A VECES LAS IMAGENES NO SE MUESTRAN EN MI FRONTEND A PESAR DE QUE SI SE GUARDAN EN MI BASE DE DATOS MONGO Y EN MI STORE DE REDUX". EN OTRAS PALABRAS SI ALGUIEN ACA LOGRA MONTAR MI PROYECTO PUEDE PROBAR VARIAS VECES, EL 90% DE LAS VECES SE TE MOSTRARAN LAS IMAGENES EN EL FRONTEND INSTANTANEMENTE PERO OTRAS VECES NO SE TE MOSTRARAN Y LO MAS EXTRAÑO SIN ERRORES Y GUARDANDOSE LAS IMAGENES EN LA BASE DE DATOS Y EN EL STORE DE REDUX, ya probe en distintos navegadores y sucede lo mismo, alguna idea de que pudiera ser ? algun genio por alli ?

ESTA ES MI ESTRUCTURA DE ARCHIVOS CREADOS CON CREATE-REACT-APP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SERVER.JS:

const express = require('express')
const Empresa = require('./Empresa')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
require('./ConexionMongo.js')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())


const diskstorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {

       cb(null, uuidv4() + path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase())  

    }
  })

const miMulter = multer({
  storage: diskstorage
}).array('file')


app.post('/guardar/post',miMulter,async (req,res)=>{
   const empresa = new Empresa({
     empresa:req.body.empresa,
     imagenes:req.files
   })

   const enviar = await empresa.save()
   res.json(enviar)

})


app.listen('3001',() => {
  console.log("Servidor arriba...")
})

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONEXION_MONGO.JS:


const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const URI = "mongodb://localhost/jehova"

mongoose.connect(URI)
        .then(db => console.log("Me conecte con mongo..."))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

module.exports = mongoose;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MODELO_EMPRESA.JS:


const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const {Schema} = mongoose


const EmpresaSchema = new Schema({
   empresa: {type:String, require:true},
   imagenes: {type:Array, require:true}   

})


module.exports = mongoose.model('Empresa',EmpresaSchema) 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
APP:

import './App.css';
import ListaImagenenes from './ListaImagenenes'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Provider store={store}>
         <ListaImagenenes/>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

------------------------------------------
LISTAIMAGENES.JS:

import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {setEmpresaList} from './reducers/empresa'
import Imagenes from './Imagenes'


function ListaImagenes(){
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()  

   const enviar = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'))

    await fetch('http://localhost:3001/guardar/post', {
      method: 'POST',
      body:  formData
    })
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => {
         console.log('Success:',res)
         dispatch(setEmpresaList(res))   

    })
    .catch(err => {
         console.error('Error:',err)
    })
    
   }  

   return (
      <div>
         <form id="form" onSubmit={enviar}>
           <input type="text" name="empresa"></input>        
           <input type="file" name="file" multiple />   
           <button>ENVIAR</button>
         </form>

       <Imagenes/>

      </div>
   )

}

export default ListaImagenes

------------------------------------------------------------------------
IMAGENES.JS

import React from 'react'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

function Imagenes(){

    const {empresa} = useSelector(state=>state.empresa)
    const {imagenes} = useSelector(state=>state.empresa)

    return (
        <div>

           <div>{empresa}</div>
                <div className='row'>
                {
                  imagenes.map((j,index)=> (                            
                    <div key={index}> 
                        <img  id="img" src={j.filename} alt="..." style={{width:'100px'}}/>
                    </div>              
                  ))
                }
           </div>

        </div>
    )

}

export default Imagenes
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STORE.JS:


import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import empresa from './reducers/empresa'

const store = configureStore({
   reducer:{
       empresa
   }
})

export default store

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REDUCER_EMPRESA.JS


import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const empresaSlice = createSlice({
  name:'empresa',
  initialState:{
      empresa:'',
      imagenes:[]
  },
  reducers:{
    setEmpresaList: (state,action) => action.payload

  }
})

export const {setEmpresaList} = empresaSlice.actions

export default empresaSlice.reducer
```

Comment: El problema que tenes, por lo cual no recibis respuesta, es que tus preguntas son poco claras, o demasia extensas (para contestar esto, habria que armarte todo un proyecto). Y si en lugar de eso, pones el codigo afectado para que puedan ayudarte y corregir el problema?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si subis con axios las imagenes, en ningun momento deberias estar recargando la pagina.. tal vez el problema es como estas subiendo? tal vez el problema es como las estas bajando?

Comment: También desde nuestro lado, hay que intentar "adivinar" muchas cosas para intentar ayudar... uno quiere, pero de solo pensar que uno está haciendo "disparos al aire" sin saber que lo que va a proponer va a funcionar o no, eso tambien desanima mucho. Si ere ´tu el que necesita ayuda, pues danos la mayor cantidad de información posible sobre el problema específico que tienes (incluido código) y seguramente tus preguntas serán resueltas rapidamente.

Comment: Para este caso puntual. 1) Que guardas en la BD? la ruta de la imagen donde quedó subida? 2) que devuelve el servidor una vez se suben? 3) es la ruta publica o la ruta privada dentro del servidor? 4) Cuando subes la imagen que almacenas en el store de redux? .... y así puedo seguir con mil dudas mas que pueden ayudar a solventar el problema